# Does NuGet automatically upgrade installed packages to new versions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nuget, nuget-package-restore, nugetgallery

I see that there are new versions of [ASP.NET MVC and Web API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/announcing-the-release-of-asp-net-mvc-5-2-web-api-2-2-and-web-pages-3-2.aspx)

If a solution references these NuGet packages, will it automatically update them to these newer versions with options set thus:

[image]

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you still need to go to the package manager, and check the updates section.

[image]

The setting here allow the project, when built for the first time, to go to nuget and fetch the dependant assemblies.  For example, if a colleague was to get the solution for the repo for the first time, when they build, all the assemblies will be downloaded.

**NOTE**: Be careful when updating, I usually tend to do it in small bunches at a time and check the solution still runs / builds after each update.

Answer (score 2):

No. NuGet does not automatically upgrade packages. If you want to update a package, you'll need to do it manually.

However, NuGet will download missing referenced packages in order to allow a project to build correctly, which is what those options reference. There's more information on Package Restore over at [NuGet.org](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore).